# Creating a player class that can be used by two different games

Tags: java

I have to write some classes for snakes and ladders and tic tac toe.

I am trying to create a Player class which is the super class of `Player_Piece` and `Player_Symbol`.

Player class has to: Create the player objects, stores the player object `states:Name`,`Score`.

`Player_Piece` has to assign the color and position to the objects which is the player piece on the game board of snakes and ladders. It also has to move the pieces

`Player_Symbol` is the class for the tic tac toe game it assigns and holds the  players symbol, (either a nought or a cross) and positions.

I am not sure if I have done these classes correctly and I would appreciate some advice on anything I should change. I am very new to java and I have been thrown into the deep end with this

Player Class

```
public class Player {

    private String PlayerName;

    public Player(String name) {
        PlayerName = name;
    }

    /**
     * This set method sets the name of the player.
     * 
     *  @param Takes in a String as name.
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.PlayerName = name;
    }

    /**
     * This get method returns the String value of player name.
     * 
     *  @return PlayerName, a String value.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return PlayerName;
    }

}
```

Player_Piece Class

```
public class Player_Piece extends Player {
    // class constants
    // Colors for the players piece 
    public static final String BLUE = "Blue";
    public static final String RED = "red";
    public static final String YELLOW = "Yellow";
    public static final String BLACK = "Black";

    // Types for each players piece. 
    public static final String PLAYER1PIECE = "player one's piece";
    public static final String PLAYER2PIECE = "player two's piece";
    public static final String PLAYER3PIECE = "player three's piece";
    public static final String PLAYER4PIECE = "player four's piece";


    // fields
    private String color;
    private String type;
    private int row;
    private int column;

    // constructors
    /**
     * Constructs a new player piece with a colour and type at the given position.
     * @param color  The piece's color must be one of the following: BLUE, RED, YELLOW or BLACK.
     * @param type   The piece's type must either PLAYER1PIECE, PLAYER2PIECE, PLAYER3PIECE, PLAYER4PIECE.
     */
    public Player_Piece(String color, String type, int row, int column) {


        this.color  = color;
        this.type   = type;
        this.row    = row;
        this.column = column;

    }

    // methods for the class
    /**
     * Returns this players piece color. 
     * @return the color; either BLUE, RED, YELLOW or BLACK.
     */
    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this player piece's type.
     * @return the type; either PLAYER1PIECE, PLAYER2PIECE, PLAYER3PIECE, PLAYER4PIECE.
     */
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this player's piece row position.
     * @return the position of the piece.
     */
    public int getRow() {
        return this.row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this player's piece column position.
     * @return the  position of the piece at the column
     */
    public int getColumn() {
        return this.column;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a String  of this piece.
     * @return a three letter String, such as "P1P" for player one's piece.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return this.type.substring(0, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Moves the piece to the  position.
     * 
     * @param row The row position for the piece to move to.
     * @param column The column position for the piece to move to.
     */
    public void move(int row, int column) {
        this.row    = row;
        this.column = column;


      }
}
```

Player_Symbol Class

```
public class Player_Symbol extends player {

    private String symbolChoice;
    private int[][] symbolPosition;

    public void setSymbol (String symbol) {
        this.symbolChoice = symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbolPos(int[][] position) {
        this.symbolPosition = position;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbolChoice;
    }

    public int[][] getSymbolPos() {
        return symbolPosition;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post just one game first and consider providing a MVC example  instead of having others wander through a 100 lines of code

Comment: In terms of Java, your code looks fine. In terms of OOP, some improvement is possible. Which doesn't mean your code is wrong; most developers would start with something similar, then continuously refactor their code as they go along. You may want to post your code on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not state a specific problem. http://codereview.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate.

Comment: Alright thanks guys i will have a rewview. Appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you expect from our answers. But if you wanna know how to create good structure of your app. There are some points related to Java.

1. Inheritance is not so good pattern. If you have really many same attributes use it. It is rather useful for extending some existing components.
2. What is important and useful is interface. For example you need methods getName, getScore, saveState etc. You create interface with these methods and then implemet it in your classes.
3. Encapsulation is also important, your attributes should be private if not necessary to be protected or public.
4. OOP - Use static attributes and methods only if it is good in that situation. For example library of math operations or logging.
5. MVC (Model View Controller) - You should separate logic, user interface and collecting user actions.
6. You can also look at some patterns like singleton or decorators.

You wrote you are new to Java so I hope you understand it.

In future your app could have structure like this:

- Entity classes mapped from your database tables
- DAO classes for accessing database (CRUD operations)
- Service classes contaning main logic of your app
- Controller classes that should colletct actions
  from user and validate data.
- UI - user interface, it depends if it is web app(jsp, jstl, jsf) or desktop app (swing, fx)

Of course there are many alternatives, that depends on your requirements and technology.

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance is not a good idea. `Player_Piece extends Player` implies 'a player's piece *is a* player', in other words 'a pawn is a human'. The fact that this is not a good representation of the real world is not even the worst part; my biggest concern is the fact that you are introducing 'code smell'.

The subclasses combine multiple responsibilities: name and position. This may sound like a total non-issue since the two responsibilities are so small. What harm is there in combining the two? Well, in my experience, every maintenance nightmare started out small. Refactor while it is still easy to do so; the longer you wait, the bigger the pain. In general, it is a violation of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). For this specific case, here's why this is bad.

### Lifetime

Name and position are likely to have different lifetime. Position only has meaning for the duration of a single game, whereas name could persist across multiple games. This is typically a sign that there should be two different objects.

### Reusability

Position is not only relevant for the player, but also for the snakes and the ladders. Right now, position is implemented in class `Player_Piece` by two integer properties `row` and `column`. Move these properties to a separate class `Position` and you will soon find that the snakes and the ladders benefit from this class too. If you don't, then you'll soon find some code duplication creeping in; `obj1.row == obj2.row && obj1.column == obj2.column` will become a recurring expression in your code. With the proper abstractions, this can be reduced to the more readable `obj1 == obj2`.

Talking of abstractions, please stop using strings for colors, types and symbols; enums are more appropriate.